# Can We remove this bevel with MeshMachine?

Tags: modifiers, add-on, edges, bevel

I'm trying to remove this kind of a bevel on this box cutter I have using MeshMachine, don't know exactly how to approach this, when trying to remove one bevel on one edge it works but when you have all edges beveled universally like this it does not, is there a way to do so using mesh machine of course.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert triangle corners to quard (select all faces of one corner and select Quard Corner from Meshmashine menu):

[image]

When unbevel it, when you will have a perfect loop flow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanx, yes it worked really appreciate it.

Comment: @AkramFex you should mark the answer as correct then.

Comment: thnx didn't know that we could do that!